# Linux log server permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, debian-jessie

I'm trying to copy few log files from the server to the local machine for further analyzing. I can log in the server with `ssh` and enter in the directory.

I try to copy the files with the command,
`scp root@logs.company.com:/srv/log/2018-05-08/payyex_prod_wallet_log  /home/cherryl/Desktop`

In the terminal I get output, `Permission denied (publickey).`. What should I do? I use a `Debian 8` machine.

Comment: You need to generate the rsa key and place it in the .ssh folder of the server logs.company.com.

Comment: This is done by the admin and hence I can log in the first place

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su] instead of here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the issue comes from permissions and ownership. maybe you just have the read privilige on that file, 
run an `ls -l` to know the priviliges you have on that file, if it is read only then try to modify them with a `chmod` command if you have the priviliges to do that.

Comment: Ok this may be the issue .. let me check.

Comment: Keep me informed

Comment: I provided myself the read access, but, this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: what you need is : 
source directory: execute and read permission 
source file: read permission.
target directory: execute and write permission.
target file: you don't need any permission since it doesn't exit before you copy it. or write permission if the file exists.
if this does not work try changing the ownership using `chown` command

Comment: it doesnt work, but I can use `tail` command to read the last 100 lines which is very handy ;-)

Comment: there are multiple ways so you can read the all the file, or just a part of it like head, tail, or both combined with a pipe, cat, nano.., i still dont get why it does not work, just make sure that you've done everything correctly.